# How to store huge amount of data in browser cache

Tags: html, local-storage

We are working on a medical viewer which streams jpeg2000 images onto the browsers and are shown in an image viewer. However, the number and the size of the images is very large and the often we need to play with hundreds of megs of images. This means we hit a restriction on the allowed cache by the browsers. what are the options that i can use which will allow me to save huge amounts of temp data on the client side?

the tech we are using is HTML5 and javascript. we hope to be able to work on all modern browsers.

thanks.

Comment: The browser cache will be a very unreliable way to handle large assets, since you are not guaranteed these will actually get cached or remain cached for any consistent amount of time. This would vary between browsers and would depend heavily on the usage patterns of that user with that particular browser (other websites visited).

Comment: The localStorage feature is not meant to be used for such large amounts of data, or at least I haven't seen anything using it in such a way.

Comment: so any ideas as to how I can store large amount of images client side?

Comment: Using Java or some more exotic browser technology. This really depends on how far you can limit the range of browsers and platforms you're looking to support. Flash would not work very well for what you're describing.

Comment: Consider alternative local storage strategies such as Indexed DB. *IndexedDB is a low-level API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, including files/blobs.* For better browser support, consider something like LocalForage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned your best bet would be the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Each modern browser implements the storage limits slightly differently, but a couple of gigabytes are generally not an issue:

- [Chrome storage limits](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/offline_storage/)
- [Firefox storage limits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#storage_limits)

Answer (score -3):

make data object using javascript. This object can hold array, and you may store your data into array.

Comment: Might want to think about deleting this answer before it gets downvoted. He wants a way to persist storage of large files across browser invocations, which won't work with your solution.